# SQlite not updating records

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sql-update, executenonquery

I'm trying to update existing records in a table, here is the table:

[image]
Here is my code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            string _FINAL_SQL = "UPDATE act_monthly_listings SET loan = " + GRAND_LOAN_TOTAL + " AND interest = " + INTEREST + " AND contr = " + GRANT_CONTRIBUTIONS + " AND payment = " + GRAND_PAYMENTS_TOTAL + " WHERE act = " + act + " AND year = " + year + " AND month = " + month + ";";
            cmd.CommandText = _FINAL_SQL;
            Clipboard.SetText(_FINAL_SQL);
            cmd.Connection = c;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

No error or exception is being thrown, but its not updating.

example `sql`:

```
UPDATE act_monthly_listings SET loan = 60 AND interest = 6 AND contr = 0 AND payment = 100 WHERE act = 93 AND year = 2014 AND month = 3;
```

I will be expecting to see the following record entry to be updated:

[image]

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(_FINAL_SQL);`  print? Run that statement against the db to see what could be missing instead.

Comment: i did, i dont see anything wrong

Comment: Well, we cannot see anything wrong either, so it must work as intended then. Why don't you show us the information you have? Show us that _FINAL_SQL and show us the record(s) in your database you expect to be updated.

Comment: Just updated the question with examples as you asked

Comment: Have you tried to run your query in a database manager tool? Same results?

Comment: Yes same results with sqlite admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is incorrect, you cannot use "AND" keyword in SET part of query, you should use comma "," to separate fields that you want to update.

Please see documentation for correct UPDATE statement syntax:
https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Your query should be:

`UPDATE act_monthly_listings SET loan = 60, interest = 6, contr = 0, payment = 100 WHERE act = 93 AND year = 2014 AND month = 3;`